# Applying advice to method private class in a ManagedBean class

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

```
public class DoOperationManagedBean
{
    private PrivateHelper privateHelper;

    public DoOperationManagedBean() {
        privateHelper = new PrivateHelper();
    }

    //Currently @Around is applied on the is method.
    public void perform(List<SomeClass> list){
        for(SomeClass sc: list) {
            privateHelper.execute(sc);
        }
    }

    private class PrivateHelper{
        //want to apply @Around on this method
        public void execute(SomeClass sc){
            //Code to process sc. 
        }
    }

}
```

I am able to apply `Around` advice on `DoOperationManagedBean.perform` method because `DoOperationManagedBean` is am Spring Managed Bean.

I need to apply `Around` advice to `PrivateHelper.execute` method. But since I can not instantiate `private` class outside `DoOperationManagedBean`, i can not make it a managed bean.

Is there any way to apply `advice` on `PrivateHelper.execute` ?

Comment: Sure you can make it a managed bean. Just that, you need to access it using `$`, and not `.` - `DoOperationManagedBean$PrivateHelper`